# Flutter : How to use Email Verification FIrebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I just finished **Firebase Auth** for my first application, but I want to add **Email Verification** when the user has Sign Up, please how can I make it.

```
class AuthServices {
      final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
  Login? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return Login(user.uid, user.email);
  }

  Stream<Login?>? get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<Login?> signUp(String email, String password, String name) async {
    final credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    UserService().createUser(name);
    return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
  }

  Future<Login?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    final credential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do your job:-

```
final firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
 if (firebaseUser.isEmailVerified){ 
       //Verified 
    } 
   else {
   firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
      }
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't think that's the answer. 
I mean, user can receive a verification email and must verify the email first in order to sign in

Comment: Hi @Juanneilp i have updated my answer

Comment: sorry, i'm still not understand, how to get method 'isEmailVerified' and 'sendEmailVerified' based my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<Login?> signUp(String email, String password, String name) async {
    final credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);

    await credential.user?.sendEmailVerification();  // Add this line

    UserService().createUser(name);
    return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
  }
```